# Is there a way to add two resource folders to aspnet core localization?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I'm currently developing the SDK for one project and as a requirement I need to add two resources locations. One will be provided with the SDK lib and another to be provided by the consumer app.

Currently, according to docs, this is how to add localization:

`services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");`

I'm calling this method from my `BaseStartup` class that will be inherited by the consumer app's `Startup` class. So I need to be able to setup the location of the SDK's resources folder and the consumer app's one as well.

Maybe something like:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => 
{
    options.ResourcesPath = "SDKResources";
    options.FromAssembly = sdkResourcesAssembly;
});
services.AddLocalization(options => 
{
    options.ResourcesPath = "AppResources";
    options.FromAssembly = appResourcesAssembly;
});
```

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, is there a workaround?

Checking online and even the source code (https://github.com/aspnet/Localization) wasn't of much help. The only thing I can think of is using `IStringLocalizerFactory` which accepts an assembly and the name of the file. Would it work? For instance, adding `services.AddLocalization()` and then just creating a wrapper class that would provide the consumer app with the strings using the factories created using `IStringLocalizerFactory`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about two ways it can be done, first by adding resources from different assemblies:

I created a base startup class to handle all source assemblies containing my resource classes and then I load them.

```
serviceCollection.AddLocalization();

var resourceTypes = typeof(BaseResource<>).Assembly.GetDerivedGenericTypes(typeof(BaseResource<>));

if (typeFromResourceAssembly != null)
    resourceTypes.AddRange(typeFromResourceAssembly.Assembly.GetDerivedGenericTypes(typeof(BaseResource<>)));

foreach (var resourceType in resourceTypes)
{
    serviceCollection.AddScoped(resourceType, resourceType);
}

return serviceCollection;
```

Second, by adding different resource folders:

```
services.Configure<ClassLibraryLocalizationOptions>(
                options => options.ResourcePaths = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "ResourceClass", "ResourcesFolder" },
                    { "Localization.CustomResourceClass", "Folder1/Folder2" }
                }
            );
```

Comment: What is your ClassLibraryLocalizationOptions in the second code block?

Comment: @rain_  It's a custom class you have to create to store the resource folders. And then you can inject it into your factory, see the example here: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/93d29fb35039c2dc7e71a998fc7ff7622f4f7e72/samples/Localization.CustomResourceManager/ClassLibraryResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory.cs

I personally prefer, and went for, the first option, but you can select the one that's best for your scenario.